# Combine multiple lines of text documents into one

Tags: python-2.7, lines

I have thousands of text documents and they have varied number of lines of texts. I want to combine all the lines into one single line in each document individually. That is for example:

```
abcd 
efgh 
ijkl
```

should become as

```
abcd efgh ijkl
```

I tried using sed commands but it is quite not achieving what I want as the number of lines in each documents vary. Please suggest what I can do. I am working on python in ubuntu. One line commands would be of great help. thanks in advance!

Comment: `with open('output.txt', 'w') as outfile, open('input.txt') as infile: outfile.write(' '.join(line.strip() for line in infile))`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget thank you so much. But I have thousands of files for which I have to process the same. How can I do it?

Comment: Just do that for each file

Comment: I have like 5000 files. Can you suggest me how to put that in a loop?

Comment: @Krupa_Code try my answer, as it includes a loop through all of your docs.  you will have to change the directory path to fit your setup.  you can do this by navigating to the directory and then (using windows) copying the address (click on the folder icon in the windows explore address bar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you place your script in the same directory as your files, the following code should work.

```
import os
count = 0
for doc in os.listdir('C:\Users\B\Desktop\\newdocs'):
    if doc.endswith(".txt"):
        with open(doc, 'r') as f:
            single_line = ''.join([line for line in f])
            single_space = ' '.join(single_line.split())

        with open("new_doc{}.txt".format(count) , "w") as doc:
            doc.write(single_space)
        count += 1
    else:
        continue
```

@inspectorG4dget's code is more compact than mine -- and thus I think it's better.  I tried to make mine as user-friendly as possible.  Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Using python wouldn't be necessary. This does the trick:

```
% echo `cat input.txt` > output.txt
```

To apply to a bunch of files, you can use a loop. E.g. if you're using `bash`:

```
for inputfile in /path/to/directory/with/files/* ; do
    echo `cat ${inputfile}` > ${inputfile}2
done
```

Comment: this is not working. The above code is working but I want to process it for a lot of files simultaneously.

Comment: I am sorry but even this is not working. The lines are remaining intact.

Answer (score 0):

assuming all your files are in one directory,have a .txt extension and you have access to a linux box with bash you can use tr like this:

```
for i in *.txt ; do tr '\n' ' ' < $i > $i.one; done
```

for every "file.txt", this will produce a "file.txt.one" with all the text on one line.

If you want a solution that operates on the files directly you can use gnu sed (NOTE THIS WILL CLOBBER YOUR STARTING FILES - MAKE A BACKUP OF THE DIRECTORY BEFORE TRYING THIS):

```
sed  -i -n 'H;${x;s|\n| |g;p};' *.txt
```

If your files aren't in the same directory, you can used find with -exec:

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec YOUR_COMMAND \{\} \;
```

If this doesn't work, maybe a few more details about what you're trying to do would help.

Comment: your `sed` version isn't quite correct, as it introduces a rogue space at the start of the combined line, e.g. it will generate `" foo bar qux"` instead of `"foo bar qux"` ... if you want to use `sed`, a more correct version is `sed  -i -n '1h;2,$H;${x;s|\n| |g;p;}' *.txt`